# Multiple Big file sort

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, awk

I have two files that each line order by timestamp but has different structure. I want merge there file info one single file and order by timestamp. look like:

file A(less than 2G)

```
1,1,1487779199850
2,2,1487779199852
3,3,1487779199854
4,4,1487779199856
5,5,1487779199858
```

file B(less than 15G)

```
1,1,10,100,1487779199850
2,2,20,200,1487779199852
3,3,30,300,1487779199854
4,4,40,400,1487779199856
5,5,50,500,1487779199858
```

how can I accomplish this? is there any way can make it as fast as possible?

Comment: what is expected o/p ?

Comment: Is the big number the timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{print $NF, $0}' fileA fileB | sort -s -n -k1,1 | cut -f2-
1,1,1487779199850
1,1,10,100,1487779199850
2,2,1487779199852
2,2,20,200,1487779199852
3,3,1487779199854
3,3,30,300,1487779199854
4,4,1487779199856
4,4,40,400,1487779199856
5,5,1487779199858
5,5,50,500,1487779199858
```

I originally posted the above as just a comment under [@VM17's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42410962/1745001) but (s)he suggested I make it a new answer.

The above would be more robust and efficient since it's using the default separator for `sort`+`cut` (tab), will truly only sort on the first key (his would use the whole line despite the `-k1` since `sort`s field separator tab isn't present in the line), uses a stable sort algorithm (`sort -s`) to preserve input order and uses `cut` to strip off the added key field which is more efficient than invoking `awk` again since `awk` does field splitting etc. on each record which isn't needed to just remove the leading field(s).

Alternatvely you might find something like this more efficient:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ currRec = $0; currKey = $NF }
NR>1 {
    print prevRec
    printf "%s", saved
    while ( (getline < "fileB") > 0 ) {
        if ($NF < currKey) {
            print
        }
        else {
            saved = $0 ORS
            break
        }
    }
}
{ prevRec = currRec; prevKey = currKey }
END {
    print prevRec
    printf "%s", saved
    while ( (getline < "fileB") > 0 ) {
        print
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk fileA
1,1,1487779199850
1,1,10,100,1487779199850
2,2,1487779199852
2,2,20,200,1487779199852
3,3,1487779199854
3,3,30,300,1487779199854
4,4,1487779199856
4,4,40,400,1487779199856
5,5,1487779199858
5,5,50,500,1487779199858
```

As you can see it reads from fileB between reads of lines fileA comparing timestamps so it's interleaving the 2 files and so doesn't require a subsequent pipe to sort and cut.

Just check the logic as I didn't think about it very much and be aware that this is a rare situation where getline might be appropriate for efficiency but make sure to read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to understand all it's caveats if you're ever considering using it again.

Comment: +1. I'm a guy btw. Not sure if OP knows enough about this website to revisit the question and unaccept and reaccept answers. Your `awk` knowledge is really spectacular. Thanks for making SO more awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
awk -F, '{print $NF, $0}' fileA fileB | sort -nk 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output-

```
1,1,10,100,1487779199850
1,1,1487779199850
2,2,1487779199852
2,2,20,200,1487779199852
3,3,1487779199854
3,3,30,300,1487779199854
4,4,1487779199856
4,4,40,400,1487779199856
5,5,1487779199858
5,5,50,500,1487779199858
```

This concatenates the two files and then puts the timestamp at the starting of the line. It then sorts according to the timestamp and then removes that dummy column.

This will be slow for big files though.

Comment: `cat fileA fileB` may not scale well when your input files are of size `2G` and `15G`

Comment: Nice approach, although the initial `cat` is unnecessary, just `awk ... fileA fileB` will do the same.

Comment: @Inian you're right but I'm not sure how else to approach the problem.

Comment: @EdMorton I think that is different enough to merit its own answer.

Comment: OK, I posted it as a new answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42420561/1745001.